# Variable shows while in loop but not out of it

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to print the first even number of "n". Somehow, when I try to print the number it would keep reading numbers on console to infinite, but when I print inside the loop it prints "66666666 etc..". This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,x=1;
    cin>>n;
    while(n){
        while(x){
            i=n%10;
            if(n%2==0){
                x--;
            }
            n/=10;
        }
    }
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger?

Comment: If you take `n` as a string, you could iterate through the string and `atoi` (convert to int) and check each of those.

Comment: Hello dr 21, welcome to Stack Overflow.

My English is probably bad, but can you explain what are you trying to achieve, or should I say, give us an example of wanted output (with it's input)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your 2 while loops:

```
while(n) {
    while(x) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Once `x` goes to 0, you end up in the outer loop.

However, this outer loop doesn't modify `n` at all. So if `n` is ever not 0, it will sit there continually.

The simplest fix is probably just combine them into a single loop:

```
while(n && x) {
    //...
}
```

Or, you can just use 1 loop and not use `x` at all.

```
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    while(n){
        i=n%10;
        if(n%2==0){
            break;
        }
        n/=10;
    }
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

That should also work as well.